# "RETURN" key press using "CurrentCharacter" returns an empty string

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am tryiing to write a GUI in which the user must enter the command (RETURN or DELETE) from the keyboard. For that purpose, I wrote a code where I set the 'KeyPressFcn' to read the key pressed by the user. The mais problem is that when the user types "RETURN" or "DELETE" all I get is an empty string.

Here is the code:

```
function getKey(axeshandle)

fig = ancestor(axeshandle, 'figure');
set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', @keyRead);
uiwait(fig);

      function keyRead(src, callback)
          key = get(fig, 'CurrentCharacter');
          strcmp(key, 'return')
          class(key)
      end

end
```

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: They're not empty strings. `'CurrentCharacter'` returns the character, not the key. ENTER returns a carriage return (ASCII 13) and DELETE returns a delete (ASCII 127).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your issue is that it *is* returning the current character, it just so happens that for the return key, that character is a carriage return character (`\r`) so it looks like an empty string. If you wanted to perform this check you could either compare to `\r` directly or it's ASCII equivalent (13).

```
% Use char(13) to create \r
strcmp(key, char(13))

% Convert char to it's ASCII representation and compare
isequal(double(key), 13)

% Create \r using sprintf
strcmp(key, sprintf('\r'))
```

Similarly, the delete key returns a [delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character) (ASCII 127).

You can check this by converting the current character to a number (it's ASCII representation)

```
double(get(src, 'CurrentCharacter'));
```

### A Better Alternative

Rather than trying to get the `CurrentCharacter` of the current figure, use the second input to your callback (the event data) to determine which key was pressed.

```
function keyRead(src, evnt)
    % Access the Key field from the event data
    key = evnt.Key;

    % Compare the value with "return"
    strcmp(key, 'return')

    % Comapre the value with delete
    strcmp(key, 'delete')
end
```